# Como esconder um texto sendo ele maior que minha Div

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

O objetivo do exercício esta voltado para estudo , estou criando um blog que possui matérias sobre dublagem e um dos objetivos é esconder o texto, que é bem maior que minha Div, assim ao clicar no post a pessoa seja redirecionada a uma página com a matéria completa.

Código HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>dublaBlog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/folhaDeEstilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1><span style="color: red">dubla</span>Blog</h1>
        <nav class="menuDaPagina">
            <ul class="listaMenu">
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Anime</a></li>
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Cartoons</a></li>
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Filmes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <article>
        <section class="postagem">
            <h4>Entrevista com Wendel Bezerra</h4>
            <span style="color: red; font-size: 12px; display: block">Postado por Rafael Boeno</span>
            <figure>
                <img src="imagens/wendel-bezerra-goku-300.png">
                <figcaption>
                    <p>Maecenas in placerat urna. Proin velit ipsum, imperdiet sit amet lorem id, malesuada pellentesque
                        risus. Duis porttitor justo sit amet malesuada varius. Nulla dignissim eros nec lectus suscipit
                        imperdiet. Vivamus tristique quis odio sed tempor. Sed pulvinar, urna a tempor sodales, purus m
                        etus mollis lectus, in congue enim nisl ut dui. Suspendisse interdum urna nec elit tincidunt por
                        ta. Duis venenatis risus in semper sodales. Praesent feugiat rutrum fermentum. Nullam luctus aug
                        ue sit amet ultrices cursus. Curabitur tristique ex at ante pharetra, quis scelerisque eros rutr
                        um. Donec commodo nibh ligula, ut elementum risus ullamcorper quis. Nunc ut nunc sem. Mauris ut
                        varius lorem, a tempor nibh. Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis
                        rhoncus lorem orciDonec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis dois tres
                        rhoncus lorem orc Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis teste um
                        rhoncus lorem orc.
                        Maecenas in placerat urna. Proin velit ipsum, imperdiet sit amet lorem id, malesuada pellentesque
                        risus. Duis porttitor justo sit amet malesuada varius. Nulla dignissim eros nec lectus suscipit
                        imperdiet. Vivamus tristique quis odio sed tempor. Sed pulvinar, urna a tempor sodales, purus m
                        etus mollis lectus, in congue enim nisl ut dui. Suspendisse interdum urna nec elit tincidunt por
                        ta. Duis venenatis risus in semper sodales. Praesent feugiat rutrum fermentum. Nullam luctus aug
                        ue sit amet ultrices cursus. Curabitur tristique ex at ante pharetra, quis scelerisque eros rutr
                        um. Donec commodo nibh ligula, ut elementum risus ullamcorper quis. Nunc ut nunc sem. Mauris ut
                        varius lorem, a tempor nibh. Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis
                        rhoncus lorem orciDonec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis dois tres
                        rhoncus lorem orc Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis teste um
                        rhoncus lorem orc.
                    </p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
    </article>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Folha de Estilo CSS3

```
body{
    background-color: #CCC5CD;
}

header{
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto 200px;
    border-bottom:  1px solid;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}


header h1{
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 141px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

nav.menuDaPagina{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

ul.listaMenu{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

li.itemMenu{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

li:hover{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
}

article{
    margin: auto 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


section.postagem{
    width: 600px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

section h4{
    display: inline;
}

figure{
    margin: 0px;
}

figure img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

figcaption p{
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode colocar `...` ao final do texto usando `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

Exemplo:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
</div>
```

Comment: Eu apliquei seu código na minha Section acredito ser a o container certo a aplicar esse código porém o resultado foi diferente do seu invés de aparecer "..." ele cortou o texto, você vê que o mesmo continua porém as palavras estão cortadas do meio para cima é complicado explicar sem uma imagem mais alterando o tamanho o height do container resolveu o problema

Comment: Isso pode acontecer mesmo @LucasAlves, a parte interessante de usar ellipsis é que fica mais elegante e intuitivo.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é mudar os estilos do `<figure>` e `section.postagem`. Setar no primeiro um `overflow: hidden;` e um `height` fixo; e no segundo apenas um `overflow: hidden;`. Isso irá delimitar o conteúdo interno à área do elemento. O que ultrapassar essa área não será visível.

> `text-overflow: ellipsis;` neste seu caso não funciona porque o texto
>   tem múltiplas linhas.

**Veja funcionando:**

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>dublaBlog</title>
   <style>
body{
    background-color: #CCC5CD;
}

header{
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto 200px;
    border-bottom:  1px solid;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}


header h1{
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 141px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

nav.menuDaPagina{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

ul.listaMenu{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

li.itemMenu{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

li:hover{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
}

article{
    margin: auto 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


section.postagem{
    width: 600px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section h4{
    display: inline;
}

figure{
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 217px;
    display: inline-block;
}

figure img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

figcaption p{
   margin: 0;
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1><span style="color: red">dubla</span>Blog</h1>
        <nav class="menuDaPagina">
            <ul class="listaMenu">
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Anime</a></li>
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Cartoons</a></li>
                <li class="itemMenu"><a href="">Filmes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <article>
        <section class="postagem">
            <h4>Entrevista com Wendel Bezerra</h4>
            <span style="color: red; font-size: 12px; display: block">Postado por Rafael Boeno</span>
            <figure>
                <img width="200" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
                <figcaption>
                    <p>Maecenas in placerat urna. Proin velit ipsum, imperdiet sit amet lorem id, malesuada pellentesque
                        risus. Duis porttitor justo sit amet malesuada varius. Nulla dignissim eros nec lectus suscipit
                        imperdiet. Vivamus tristique quis odio sed tempor. Sed pulvinar, urna a tempor sodales, purus m
                        etus mollis lectus, in congue enim nisl ut dui. Suspendisse interdum urna nec elit tincidunt por
                        ta. Duis venenatis risus in semper sodales. Praesent feugiat rutrum fermentum. Nullam luctus aug
                        ue sit amet ultrices cursus. Curabitur tristique ex at ante pharetra, quis scelerisque eros rutr
                        um. Donec commodo nibh ligula, ut elementum risus ullamcorper quis. Nunc ut nunc sem. Mauris ut
                        varius lorem, a tempor nibh. Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis
                        rhoncus lorem orciDonec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis dois tres
                        rhoncus lorem orc Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis teste um
                        rhoncus lorem orc.
                        Maecenas in placerat urna. Proin velit ipsum, imperdiet sit amet lorem id, malesuada pellentesque
                        risus. Duis porttitor justo sit amet malesuada varius. Nulla dignissim eros nec lectus suscipit
                        imperdiet. Vivamus tristique quis odio sed tempor. Sed pulvinar, urna a tempor sodales, purus m
                        etus mollis lectus, in congue enim nisl ut dui. Suspendisse interdum urna nec elit tincidunt por
                        ta. Duis venenatis risus in semper sodales. Praesent feugiat rutrum fermentum. Nullam luctus aug
                        ue sit amet ultrices cursus. Curabitur tristique ex at ante pharetra, quis scelerisque eros rutr
                        um. Donec commodo nibh ligula, ut elementum risus ullamcorper quis. Nunc ut nunc sem. Mauris ut
                        varius lorem, a tempor nibh. Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis
                        rhoncus lorem orciDonec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis dois tres
                        rhoncus lorem orc Donec iaculis aliquet est, vitae feugiat turpis porttitor vel. Duis teste um
                        rhoncus lorem orc.
                    </p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
    </article>
    <footer>

    </footer>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar `text-overflow: ellipsis;` e `white-space: nowrap;` **vai limitar o seu texto a apenas uma linha**.

Para múltiplas linhas não vai funcionar. Se vc quiser osar os 3 pontinhos em textos com mais de uma linha veja como fazer.

Modelo com o `Ellipsis` para dentro do TextBox. *(essa opção pode depender de ajuste fino no Padding para ficar ao seu gosto e não cortar um caractere no meio por exemplo)*

```css
/* Modelo da caixa de texto */
.block-with-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    max-height: 6em; /* aqui vc controla a altura da caixa de texto */
    text-align: justify;
}
.block-with-text:before {
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 0px 0 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<p class="block-with-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, veniam! Officiis assumenda iusto ad corrupti fuga nobis earum laborum alias quam rerum quae molestias ipsum soluta eveniet quos ut illo necessitatibus unde quidem consequatur dolorem, nemo minus! Fugiat, asperiores vel. Possimus rerum enim facilis aspernatur iure doloribus ut commodi cumque nam omnis porro quibusdam voluptatibus, alias eum! Hic modi provident assumenda mollitia sunt non culpa, sapiente est officia a, quis illum quos nesciunt. Enim aliquid eaque a adipisci ullam, minus dolor accusantium corrupti dolore soluta voluptate ipsa harum pariatur vel ut cupiditate dolorem velit ab ex ratione est assumenda ipsum!</p>
```

Opção com o `Ellipsis` para fora da caixa do texto. Assim não vai cortar caractere.

```css
html, body {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Modelo da caixa de texto */
.block-with-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 6em; /* aqui vc controla a altura da caixa de texto */
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.block-with-text:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="block-with-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, veniam! Officiis assumenda iusto ad corrupti fuga nobis earum laborum alias quam rerum quae molestias ipsum soluta eveniet quos ut illo necessitatibus unde quidem consequatur dolorem, nemo minus! Fugiat, asperiores vel. Possimus rerum enim facilis aspernatur iure doloribus ut commodi cumque nam omnis porro quibusdam voluptatibus, alias eum! Hic modi provident assumenda mollitia sunt non culpa, sapiente est officia a, quis illum quos nesciunt. Enim aliquid eaque a adipisci ullam, minus dolor accusantium corrupti dolore soluta voluptate ipsa harum pariatur vel ut cupiditate dolorem velit ab ex ratione est assumenda ipsum!</p>
```